# Parallel Port OFF control using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, parallel-processing, port

good day!

I have been coding for a parallel port project which outputs to a group of Light emitting diodes. Here are it's  [main controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/719MC.png)

in order to turn it on, it made a variable that increments according to the checkbox, with 1 being the lowest and 255 the highest..

The first checkbox

```
 Dim intval2write As Integer
 intval2write = intval2write + 1
```

The second checkbox

```
 Dim intval2write As Integer
 intval2write = intval2write + 2
```

The third checkbox

```
 Dim intval2write As Integer
 intval2write = intval2write + 4
```

The last  checkbox

```
 Dim intval2write As Integer
 intval2write = intval2write + 128
```

Now, my code to turn on the LED's

```
Try
        Out(&H378, intval2write)
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Turned On!" & vbNewLine & "Code " & intval2write, "USeP Electrical System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
```

Now, my question would be, can I do that with an OFF function? Can you give me good approaches in order to turn off the data lines of the parallel port..

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your ON code can be improved. For example, applying the first one twice will result in doing the second one once. What you really want to do are logical bit-wise operations. So, instead of `intval2write = intval2write + 1`, try:

```
intval2write = intval2write Or 1
```

In order to turn off the line, you want to clear the appropriate bit. We can use a logical and operations for that.

```
intval2write = intval2write And Not 1
```

For other lines, replace the 1 with 2, 4, 8, etc.

You can read more about this here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/113476.

Comment: Here is a better reference: http://www.jameshbyrd.com/using-bitwise-operators-in-vb/.

Comment: Thanks sir! I am now gonna try this one :D